# Contextual Filters using YYYY and MM

Tags: views

I am attempting to set up a list of articles that will display like so

2014
January
February

2013
January
Feb

I've set up my view, but once I use the YYYY contextual filter, it simply sorts it

2014
2013

And I cannot get the months to display. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

When I print the array the [url] returns /posts-by-date/2014

I am trying to have the array return posts-by-date/2014/[month]

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by setting up two displays of my view

Display 1 is a page display, with the path 'foo/date/%/%'.  This then gets a pair of contextual filters, the first is for the year (the first argument).  The second is for the month (the second argument).

Display 2 is a page display, with the path 'foo/date/%'.  This gets a single contextual filters, the year.